# Simple beginner Rust CLI file reader that prints to stdout

Tags: beginner, comparative-review, file, io, rust

**Q: Am I approaching writing idiomatic Rust code correctly?**

Hi CodeReview, I'm a beginner Rustacean coming from Python going through Rust books (The Rust Book, Rust in Action). A lot of the beginner code has unwrap everywhere and I'd like to write more idiomatic Rust.

I wrote 2 versions of a simple CLI program that reads a file and prints it to stdout, one with `.unwrap` and one without.

Both version execute successfully and do the same thing, only differing in the error-handling.

I tried to expand out all cases of `.unwrap` based on things in the official docs about using `.unwrap`[[1]](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap)[[2]](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/error.html)[[3]](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html).

## Protoyping

```rust
extern crate clap;

use std::{
    prelude,
    io::{BufRead, BufReader},
    fs::File,
};
use clap::{App, Arg};

fn main() {
    let matches = App::new("File reader")
        .about("Read a file line by line")
        .help("The help text")
        .version("0.1")
        .arg(Arg::with_name("input")
            .value_name("INPUT")
            .takes_value(true)
            .help("Any text file to be read"))
        .get_matches();

    // Get input argument, ensure it is valid
    let input = matches.value_of("input").unwrap();

    // Try and open the file
    let f = File::open(input).unwrap();

    // Load the file into BufReader
    let reader = BufReader::new(f);

    // Read the lines of the file
    for line_ in reader.lines() {
        let line = line_.unwrap();
        println!("{}", line);
        }
    }
```

## Improving robustness

```rust
use std::{
    error::Error,
    // prelude::*,
    io::{BufRead, BufReader},
    fs::File,
};
use clap::{App, Arg};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let matches = App::new("File reader")
        .about("Read a file line by line")
        .help("The help text")
        .version("0.1")
        .arg(Arg::with_name("input")
            .value_name("INPUT")
            .takes_value(true)
            .help("Any text file to be read"))
        .get_matches();

    // Get input argument, ensure it is valid
    let input = matches.value_of("input");

    let input = match input {
        Some(file) => file,
        None => matches.usage(),
    };

    // Try and open the file
    let f = File::open(input)?;

    // Load the file into BufReader
    let reader = BufReader::new(f);

    // Read the lines of the file
    // "if let" reads "if 'let' destructures line_ into Ok(line) value, evaluate {}"
    for line_ in reader.lines() {
        if let Ok(line) = line_ {
            println!("{}", line);
        };
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Am I approaching making my code more idiomatic correctly?

**Edit 2**: My second take at making it more readable/idiomatic (`fn main` only)

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let matches = App::new("File reader")
        .about("Read a file line by line")
        .help("The help text")
        .version("0.1")
        .arg(Arg::with_name("input")
            .value_name("INPUT")
            .takes_value(true)
            .help("Any text file to be read"))
        .get_matches();

    // Get input argument, ensure it is valid
    let input = match matches.value_of("input") {
        Some(input) => input,
        None        => matches.usage(),
    };

    // Try and open the file
    if let Ok(f) = File::open(input){
        // If valid, load into BufReader then read the file line by line
        let reader = BufReader::new(f);
        for line_ in reader.lines() {
            if let Ok(line) = line_ {
                println!("{}", line);
            };
        };
    } else {
        // If file is not valid, print the CLI usage
        println!("{}", matches.usage())
    };
    Ok(())
}
```